# How do I share 2 variables across 2 activities

Tags: java, android

```
 public void select(View v) {
        ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) v;
        //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), level1_game.class));
        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), charicter.class));
    }

    public void loadout(View v) {
        Button Button = (Button) v;
        coinvar = coinvar +1;
        TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coin1);
        mTextView.setText(Integer.toString(coinvar));
        //startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), charicter.class));
    }
}
```

Now as I switch activities I am trying to display the same number but it does not seem to work and I get a error java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference

Here is the other activity I am changing to.

```
 int mcoin = ((level) getApplicationContext()).coinvar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_charicter);
    TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.coin2);
    mTextView.setText(Integer.toString(mcoin));
```

Is there any way to do this simple and easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are trying to send only an `int` variable to the 2nd activity and doing nothing else. For this problem I suggest to send it by the `Intent`:

In first activity:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), charicter.class).putExtra("coins",coinvar));
```

In second activity:

```
private coinvar;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
...
coinvar=getIntent().getIntExtra("coins",coinvar);
```

Note that it leads to an one-way data share.

Comment: in the first activity i have this    public int coinvar =0; can i still use it

Comment: @unnamed If you want to modify the value of coinvar from the second activity, try Alireza 's code.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class and define two static value in it.

```
public class SharedValue {
   public static int value1;
   public static int value2;
}
```

Then in each of your activities you can use `SharedValue.value1` for example to set and get the value.

Also you can do it without static fields, just put this fields inside the Application class. If you don't have an application class you can in define it by inheriting from `Application`, Then you have to go to manifest file and update the application name filed. Unlike activities application will be alive while your app is open and your data will not get lost.

Answer (score 0):

Any object being public static can be accessed from anywhere, you can store them wherever you want, maybe an Activity, Service, etc.
But I would suggest you to store them in your custom Application class since it is always running. If you store the shared values in an Activity you have to deal with memory leaks.

if you do

```
public class MyApp extends Application{
    public static int sharedValue1;
    public static int sharedValue2;
}
```

Then you can access those with MyApp.sharedValue1, or if you want to implement some logic to the getters you could do:

```
getApplicationContext().getSharedValue1();
```

if you can not call getApplicationContext(), then create a method inside MyApp:

```
public static Context getAppContext(){
    return this;
}
```

then
`MyApp.getAppContext().getSharedValue1();`

Comment: I am not an android expert, but why would it be bad? I said that indeed this causes memory leaks, but an Application instance will be always alive, so from my understanding, it is not a problem as long as we share variables inside our custom Application class (not Activity or Service or whatever, but **Application**).